# Error running Kafka on Cloudera quickstart: assembly-package-dependency not valid

Tags: sbt, apache-kafka, sbt-assembly, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I have downloaded Kafka from apache and extracted it to its own folder. Following the quickstart, I also installed sbt, but at the third line in the sbt commands (I am launching the terminal from INSIDE the kafka folder, I get:

```
[error] Not a valid command: assembly-package-dependency
[error] Not a valid project ID: assembly-package-dependency
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: assembly-package-dependency (similar: sbt-dependency)
[error] assembly-package-dependency
[error]                             ^
```

I have been looking for all day for an answer, but found none which would start my server. The exception when I try the kafka-server-start.sh is always

```
unable to find main class Kafka.kafka
```

I also tried "gradle" the first time, but the problem was the same. I have no chance of upgrading to Cloudera-Express to use the parcel installer: my PC is not good enough to support it.
I am quite desperate: please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that sbt update etc didn't quite do the job, so in the end I found another answer suggesting:

In the kafka folder:

```
./gradlew jar
```